# What are the authentic, standard supplications (A'dyiah) and rememberances (Adhkar) after the Prayer?

Tags: dua, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, dhikr

Which Ahadith and references from the scholars could be provided to answer this question?

---

<sup>Continuation of "[the authentic supplications (A'dyiah) during the Tashahhud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74217/what-are-the-authentic-supplications-adyiah-during-the-tashahhud)."</sup>

Comment: In my opinion such questions are rather subjective and hard to coevr entirely. I strongly sugegst you to make a focus on authentic suppications from both sahihs or at elast a restricted list of sources. As covering all "authentic" hadith on that topic will never have a satisfactory answer! The same may apply to your linked question!

Comment: Where do you see subjectivity in this at all, when I am quoting the Hadith, the scholars and their commentary/classification? And I am posting all of the known narrations that are only authentic, and when finalised, you can gladly use "edit" to recommend any missing ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Supplications** (*A'diyah*) **and Rememberances** (*Adhkar*) **after the Prayer:**

Right after the Taslim (after Salam):

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*When (I) wanted to turn from (my) Salat, (I) would seek forgiveness from Allah* (Astaghfirullah) *three times, then say: Ya Allah, you are the One free of defects and perfection is from You - Blessed are You, O Possesor of Majesty and Honor.*" (Allahumma antas-salam, wa minkas-salam, tabarakta ya dhal-jalali wal-ikram)
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([300](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:300)), which Abu I'sa classed Hasan Sahih</sup>

Subsequently, it is narrated:

> When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) finished the prayer and pronounced salutation, he uttered (this supplication): "*There is no god but Allah, He is alone, Who has no partner, to Him belongs the sovereignty and to Him praise is due and He is Potent over everything - Ya Allah, no one can withhold what Thou givest, or give what Thou withholdest, and the riches cannot avail a wealthy person with Thee.*" (La ilaha illallah, wahdahu la sharika lah, lahul mulk, wa lahul hamd, wa huwa a'la kulli shay-in qadir¹ - Allahumma la mani'a lima a'tayt, wa la mu'tiya lima man'at, wa la yanfa'u dhal jad-di minkal jad-d)
>
> <sup>Muslim ([593a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:593a)) | It should be noted that the increase of reciting it¹ three times or other additions are anomalies and extensively answered by Shaykh Albani in Ad-Da'ifah (12/209-20 - #[5598](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/7950))</sup>
>
> <sup>And, in ([594a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:594a)), as well as Musnad Ahmad ([16105](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/12572#p1)) with addition in parentheses:</sup>
>
> " ¹ - *To Him belong all bounties, to Him belongs all Grace, and to Him is worthy praise accorded. There is no god but Allah, to Whom we are sincere in devotion, even though the unbelievers should disapprove it.*" (La ilaha illallah, wahdahu la sharika lah, lahul mulk, wa lahul hamd, wa huwa a'la kulli shay-in qadir - La hawla wa la quw-wata illa billah, la ilaha illallah, wa la na'budu illa iy-yah, (wa) lahun-ni'mat, wa lahul fadl, wa la huth-thana-ul hasan, la ilaha illallah, Mukhlisina lahud-dina wa lau karihal kafirun) [The narrator said]: 'He (the Holy Prophet ﷺ) uttered it at the end of every (obligatory) prayer.'
>
> ---

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Shall I not teach you something by which you will catch upon those who have preceded you, and get ahead of those who come after you, only those who do as you do being more excellent than you?*" 'They said: Yes, Messenger of Allah.' He said: "*Glory is to Allah, Praise be to Allah and Allah is the most Great*" (Subhanallah - Alhamdulillah - Allahu Akbar) 33 times after every prayer
>
> <sup>Muslim ([595a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:595a))</sup>
>
> <sup>Furthermore, an additional version to the above, in ([597a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:597)):</sup>
>
> : "... *and* (then) *says, to complete a hundred: "There is no god but Allah, having no partner with Him, to Him belongs sovereignty and to Him is praise due, and He is Potent over everything* (La ilaha illallah, wahdahu la sharika lah, lahul mulk, wa lahul hamd, wa huwa a'la kulli shay-in qadir), *his sins will be forgiven even if these are as abundant as the foam of the sea.*"
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Moreover, in ([595b](https://sunnah.com/muslim:595b)):</sup>
>
> - (11x Subhanallah) (11x Alhamdulillah) (11x Allahu Akbar) - to total them to 33 times
>
> <sup>Similarly, to reach a hundred, with the statement that who says them "... *after every prescribed prayer will never be caused disappointment* ..." in ([596a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:596a)):</sup>
>
> - (33x Subhanallah) (33x Alhamdulillah) (34x Allahu Akbar)
>
> <sup>A different one, which is narrated in Sunan an-Nasa'i ([1350](https://shamela.ws/book/829/2177#p1)/[1](https://shamela.ws/book/829/2178#p1)) and graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani, to say:</sup>
>
> - (25x Subhanallah) (25x Alhamdulillah) (25x Allahu Akbar) (25x La ilaha illallah)
>
> <sup>And lastly, in Al-Bukhari ([6329](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6329)):</sup>
>
> - (10x Subhanallah) (10x Alhamdulillah) (10x Allahu Akbar)
>
> ---
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*There are two practices that will admit a Muslim into Paradise if he preserves them both. They are easy, although there are few who practice them. It is to glorify Allah ten times, to praise Allah ten times, and to exalt Allah ten times at the end of every prayer* [...] *And it is to glorify Allah thirty three times, to praise Allah thirty three times, and to exalt Allah thirty four times before going to sleep* [...]" They said: 'O Messenger of Allah, how are they easy but few practice them?' The Prophet said: "*Satan comes to one of you during prayer and incites him to remember a need, so he leaves the prayer without saying them. And Shaytan comes to him when he goes to bed and lulls him to sleep without saying them.*"
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([5065](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5065)), Adab al-Mufrad ([1216](https://sunnah.com/adab/50/12)) and others, graded Sahih in Sahih at-Targhib ([606](https://shamela.ws/book/171/386#p1), [1594](https://shamela.ws/book/171/886))</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>You can chose any version for any of the 5 obligatory prayers, sometimes just one version for the whole day, sometimes you chose each one for each prayer, and so on.</sup></sup>

> <sup>Ibn U'mar said: 'Whoever says the following after every (obligatory) prayer, and when he goes to bed: (3x) Allah is the Most Great, the number of the even and the odd, and the blessed, pure, perfect words of Allah / (3x) There is no god but Allah, the number of the even and the odd, and the blessed, pure, perfect words of Allah (Allahu akbaru kabira, a'dadash-shaf'i wal witr, wa kalimatil-lahit-tamat, at-tay-yibatil mubarakat / La ilaha illallah, ...) - they will be light for him in his grave, and light on the Jisr (bridge), and light on the Sirat (bridge over Hell), until they admit him to Paradise, or until he enters Paradise.'</sup>
>
> <sup>Ibn Abi Shaybah ([29256](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/33145#p1)) | Analysis: The narrator named Taysalah is Ibn A'li, and it is related that Ibn Mayyas, Ibn Ma'in and Ibn Hibban trusted him, and a group of trustworthy people narrated from him. Al-Hafiz said in At-Taqrib: 'Acceptable.' Shaykh Albani commented in As-Sahihah ([6/940](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/4468)): 'He is [rather] trustworthy as Ibn Ma'in said, according to what Ibn Abi Hatim narrated from him.' And Muhammad ibn Abd al-Rahman, he is Muhammad ibn Abd al-Rahman ibn Ubayd al-Qurashi at-Taymi, the mawla of the Talha family, a trustworthy Muslim man, which Ibn Rajab mentioned in his book Fath al-Bari ([7/397](https://shamela.ws/book/137/3651)), and Masar, who is Ibn Kadam, as well as Yazid Ibn Harun, are two well-known trustworthy men among the narrators of the six books; and Al-Hindi graded its Isnad Hasan in Al-Kanz ([4967](https://shamela.ws/book/2677/1366))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Al-Jisr probably refers to this narration which is in Al-Bukhari ([2440](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2440)), where the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*When the believers pass safely over (the bridge across - As-Sirat) Hell, they will be stopped at a bridge* [Jisr] *in between Hell and Paradise where they will retaliate upon each other for the injustices done among them in the world, ...*" - and Allah knows best.

> Bar'a reported: 'I heard [the Prophet (ﷺ), after the Prayer] say': "*O my Lord, save me from Thy torment on the Day when Thoil, wouldst raise - or gather - Thy servants*" (Rabbi qini a'dhabak(a), yauma tab'athu - (or) tajma'u - i'badak)
>
> <sup>Muslim ([709a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:709a))</sup>

> [...] [Allah] says: "***Ask!***" (Muhammed ﷺ) said: "*Ya Allah, I ask of you the doing of the good deeds, avoiding the evil deeds, loving the poor, and that You forgive me, and have mercy upon me. And when You have willed Fitnah in the people, then take me without the Fitnah. And I ask You for Your love, the love of whomever You love, and the love of the deeds that bring one nearer to Your love.*" (Allahumma inni asaluka fi'lal khayrat, wa tarkal munkarat, wa hub-bal masakin, wa an taghfira li wa tar-hamni wa idha a-rad-ta fit-nata-qaumin fatawaf-fani ghayra maftun, asaluka hub-baka wa hub-ba man yuhib-buka wa hub-ba a'malin yuqar-ribu ila hub-bik)
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([3235](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3235)) Abu I'sa said: 'I asked Muhammad bin Isma'il [Al-Bukhari] and he said: 'This Hadith is Hasan Sahih'; and in ([3233](https://shamela.ws/book/1435/5362)), which Shaykh Albani classed Sahih in Adh-Dhal ([388](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x0iI.png)) and in his As-Siraj al-Munir ([441](https://shamela.ws/book/18571/109)), it indicates that you say this after the prayer because in this next Hadith, Allah says:</sup>
>
> "***O Muhammad, when you have performed Salah, say:***" (Allahumma inni asaluka fi'lal khayrat, wa tarkal munkarat, wa hub-bal masakin, wa idha a-rad-ta bi-i'badika fitnatan, faq-bidni ilayka ghayra maftun)

> 'A man from the Ansar told [...]: I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say at the end of the prayer: "*Ya Allah, forgive me and turn to me - You are the Ever-Turning back (to his slaves), the Merciful.*" - 100 times.' (Allahum-maghfirli wa tub a'lay-ya - Innaka antat-tau-wabul Ghafur)
>
> <sup>Ibn Abi Shaybah ([29266](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/33155)) as well as Musnad Ahmad ([23150](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/19271#p1)) graded Sahih in As-Sahihah (6/200 - #[2603](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/3728#p1))</sup>

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever recites Ayatul-Kursi after each prescribed Prayer, nothing will be standing between him and Paradise, except death.*"
>
> <sup>Sunan al-Kubra ([9848](https://shamela.ws/book/8361/13565#p1)) Ibn Hajar classed it Hasan Gharib in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([2/294](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n294/mode/2up)); and in Mu'jam al-Kabir ([7532](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/9299)), which Shaykh Albani graded Sahih in As-Sahihah (2/561-5 - #[972](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/1603#p1)) - Interestingly, there is an addition by Muhammad ibn Ibrahim in the narration of At-Tabarani, stating that Surah Ihlas is included in this, and Shaykh Albani has quoted Imam Daraqutni in Silsilah ad-Da'ifah ([6012](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/8806)), who said about the narrator: 'He is a liar.' Therefore, this addition is to be ignored.</sup>

> U'qbah ibn A'mir related: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) commanded me to recite Mu'awwidhatan (the last two Surat of the Qur'an) after every prayer.
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([1523](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1523)) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani - It should be noted that there are many narrations which include Surah Ihlas too to be recited after every prayer, but Ibn Hajar extensively refuted this in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([2/291](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n290/mode/2up)-3 - [2/347](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n346/mode/2up))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>In Abu Dawud ([1463](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1463)), graded Sahih, it is narrated that the Prophet (ﷺ) told U'qbah about "Falaq and Nas":</sup>
>
> [...] "*use them when seeking refuge in Allah, for no one can use anything to compare with them for that purpose.*" [...]
>
> <sup>And, in Ibn Majah ([3511](https://al-maktaba.org/book/810/3511)), graded Sahih, that Abu Sa'id said:</sup>
>
> 'The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to seek refuge from the evil eye of the jinn and of mankind. When the Mu'awwidhatain were revealed, he started to recite them and stopped reciting anything else.'

When you finish (and leave your place):

> When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) [...] prayed [...] and A'ishah asked him about those words, he (ﷺ) said: "*If he has spoken some good words (and he says this statement of remembrance), it will be a seal for them to preserve them until the Day of Resurrection, and if he has said something other than that, it (these words) will be an expiation for him: Glory and praise be to You, Ya Allah, I seek Your forgiveness and I repent to You.*" (Subhanakal-lahumma wa bihamdik, astaghfiruka wa atubu ilayk)
>
> <sup>Sunan an-Nasa'i ([1344](https://shamela.ws/book/829/2165#p1)); and in Sunan al-Kubra ([10067](https://shamela.ws/book/8361/13837)) as well as in A'mal al-Yawm wal-Laylah ([308](https://shamela.ws/book/6772/141#p1)), A'ishah said:</sup>
>
> <sup>'Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) did not sit in a gathering, and did not recite the Qur'an, and did not perform any prayer, without concluding it by saying:' "*... I bear witness that there is none worthy of worship but You ...*" (Subhanaka wa bihamdik, la ilaha illa ant, astaghfiruka wa atubu ilayk); and in ([10160](https://shamela.ws/book/8361/13947)) with "Subhanakal-lahumma [...] (wa) la..." - in Ad-Du'a ([1912](https://shamela.ws/book/13016/2081)) with parenthesis.</sup>
>
> <sup>Shaykh Albani classed them Sahih in As-Sahihah (7/493-6 - #[3164](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/5302)) as well as Ibn Hajar in his Tahqiq of An-Nukat ([2/733](https://shamela.ws/book/8316/707#p1))</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>It should be noted that some people say 'Sadaqallahul A'dhim' when finishing to recite the Qur'an, which has no basis at all and is considered a Bid'ah (innovation).</sup></sup>

---

- Special mention:

> A'ishah bint Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas narrated from her father that he entered with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) upon a women, before her was a date-seed – or he said – stone – that she would make Tasbih with. So he (ﷺ) said: "*Should I not inform you of what is easier for you then this, and better?*" (Subhanallahi a'dada ma khalaqa fis-sama, wa subhanallahi a'dada ma khalaqa fil ard, wa subhanallahi a'dada ma bayna dhalik, wa subhanallahi a'dada ma huwa khaliqun) [then:] "*and Allah is great, in similar amount to that, and all praise is due to Allah, in similar amount to that, and there is no might or power except by Allah, in similar amount to that*" (Allahu akbaru... - Alhamdulillahi... - La ilaha illallahu... - La haula wa la quw-wata illa billahi...)
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([3568](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3568)), which Abu I'sa classed Hasan Gharib, and in Sharh as-Sunnah ([1279](https://shamela.ws/book/7891/1979#p1)), which Al-Baghawi classed Hasan Gharib and Gharib in Masabih as-Sanah ([1656](https://shamela.ws/book/14119/725))</sup>
>
> <sup>Issue in the Isnad: The narrator Khuzaymah, who is relating from A'ishah bint S'ad bin Abi Waqqas, is unknown and the narrator Sayd ibn Abi Halal, whose memory was disrupted, according to Ahmad ibn Hanbal; graded Da'if by Shaykh Albani and he explained it in Da'if Abu Dawud ([265](https://shamela.ws/book/5914/498#p1)) and in Da'if Ibn Hibban ([296](https://shamela.ws/book/17352/192#p1))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Moreover, linked to this matter of using pebbles, stones or the 'tasbih':
>
> <sup>It is narrated in Musnad Daylami ([6765](https://shamela.ws/book/6072/1837)): "*What a good reminder the subhah is*", which Shaykh Albani classed Mawd'u in Ad-Dai'fah (1/184-93 - #[83](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/200)). Further, in Tarikh Jurjan ([94](https://shamela.ws/book/11077/71)) it is narrated that the Prohpet (ﷺ) would have used pebbles, classed Mawd'u in Ad-Dai'fah (3/47-9 - #[1002](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/1458)).</sup>
>
> <sup>And, with a Sahih Isnad ([1/186](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/202)) it is narrated by Ibn Waddah in Al-Bid'a ([21](https://shamela.ws/book/8208/22)):</sup>
>
> 'Ibn Mas'ud passed by a woman who had a [masbahah] with which she was making tasbih, and he broke it and threw it aside, then he passed by a man who was making tasbih with pebbles, and he kicked him, then said: 'You think you are better than the Sahabah, but you are following unjustified bid'a! You think you have more knowledge than the Companions of Muhammad (ﷺ)?'
>
> <sup>It is narrated in Musnad Darimi ([210](https://shamela.ws/book/21795/235)) that Ibn Mas'ud said to A'mr ibn Yahya's grandfather, after seeing people in circles who were making Dhikr in congregation and using pebbles:</sup>
>
> 'Why did you not tell them to count their bad deeds and guarantee them that nothing of their good deeds would be wasted?' Then he left, and we went with him, until he reached one of those circles. He stood over them and said: 'What is this I see you doing?' They said: 'O Abu A'bdur-Rahman, these are pebbles we are using to count our takbir, tahlil and tasbih.' He said: 'Count your bad deeds, and I guarantee that nothing of your good deeds will be wasted. Woe to you, O Ummah of Muhammad, how quickly you are getting destroyed! The companions of your Prophet are still alive, his garment is not yet worn out and his vessels are not yet broken. By the One in Whose hand is my soul, either you are following a way that is more guided than that of Muhammad or you have opened a door of misguidance!'  They said: 'By Allah, O Abu A'bdur-Rahman, we only wanted to do good.' He said: 'How many of those who wanted to do good have failed to achieve it! The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) told us that people recite Qur'an and it does not go any further than their throats. By Allah, I do not know, maybe most of them are people like you.' Then he turned away from them. A'mr bin Salamah said: 'I saw most of the men of those circles fighting alongside the Khawarij on the day of Nahrawan.'
>
> ---
>
> <sup>After all, we have a **general** Hadith related to the above mentioned one in At-Tirmidhi, that it is narrated in Ibn Hibban ([830](https://shamela.ws/book/641/1795)), which Shaykh Albani classed Hasan Sahih in Taliqat al-Hasan as well as in As-Sahihah (6/157-9 - #[2578](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/3687#p1)), and Hasan by Ibn Hajar in Al-Futuhat ([1/244](https://shamela.ws/book/23625/242)) as well as Nata'ij al-Afkar ([1/80-5](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/01_101273/page/n80/mode/2up)); without mentioning pebbles, that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*Shall I not tell you more or better than your remembrance of the night with the day and the day with the night? You say:* (Subhanallahi a'dada ma khalaqa, wa subhanallahi mil-a ma khalaqa, wa subhanallahi a'dada ma fil ard(i) was-sama, wa subhanallahi mil-a ma fil ard(i) was-sama, wa subhanallahi a'dada ma ahsa kitabuh(u), wa subhanallahi a'dada kulli shay(-in), wa subhanallahi mil-a kulli shay(-in))" *And you say:* (Elhamdulillahi...) *in similar amount to that.*"

---