# How to make Shaitaan leave me alone and not attack me all the time?

Tags: allah, shaitan, dhikr

I have heard that shaitan was afraid of Umar Ibn-e-Khattab (May Allah be pleased with him).

Since after Ramadan, Shaitan is not leaving me alone. He is constantly attacking me by means of doubts in my heart, derailing my focus, causing me depression and anxiety and hopelessness, and putting me in a disconnected and lost, despaired state.

I really want to get rid of Shaitan the rejected. Is it possible that he stays away from me and leave me alone, with Allah's help inshaAllah?

Comment: Inshallah this https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/what-are-the-authentic-supplications-adyiah-and-rememberances-adhkar-at-faj/75499#75499 or this https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75216/what-to-say-during-times-of-distress-difficulty-or-calamity/75217#75217 will help you a lot. Read everything carefully and attentively.

Answer (score 1):

Adhkaar(plural)/Zikr(Singular). Allah says

> And whosoever turns away from the remembrance of Allah, We(Allah)
> **appoint for him Shaitan** to be a Qarîn (a companion) to him. Quran
> 43:36

Hence we need to remember Allah the way Prophet(ﷺ) remembered, which is through Adhkaar proven from his Sunnah. I refer to Fortress of Muslim(Hisnul Muslim) for authentic adhkaar.

Answer (score 0):

Do not concentrate on the disturbances.
Do not fear Shaitan.

But love God by all your mind and all your heart and be grateful for all He gives us and serve Him with joy.
Do not start thinking from fear of sin but start from the thought to do good. Ask: Where am I needed, how can I do good? And: What is necessary and what is vain?

God promised Jannah to all those who believe in Him and do good. This promise is repeated so many times in the Quran that I cannot list all those passages.

Why do I recommend you to do it this way?

Because God will give you the force and the will to follow His path if you open your heart to Him and trust in His Guidance.