# Which A'dhkar and A'diyah at Fajr, A'sr and Maghrib appear to be authentic?

Tags: hadith, dua, uloom-al-hadith, dhikr

Which Ahadith and references from the scholars could be provided to answer this question?

<sup>- I will post an answer to this question</sup>

<sup>- Square brackets [ ] are additions or/and individual changes (for clarity) of the author's thread</sup>

Comment: have a look at https://www.duas.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whoever sends blessings upon [the Prophet ﷺ] 10 times in the morning and 10 times in the evening, will have [his] intercession on the Day of Resurrection.
>
> <sup>Ibn Abi Asim in his Kitab As-Salah ([61](https://shamela.ws/book/26823/62)) | Initially, Shaykh Albani graded this Hadith Hasan in Sahih al-Jam'i ([6357](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/1022)), but ultimately recanted in his Ad-Da'ifah (12/633-5 - #[5788](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/8390)) by grading its Isnad Da'if.</sup>

> If you wake up in the morning, reach the evening or retire to bed, to say: Allahumma fatiras-samawati wal ard, a'limal ghaybi wash-shahadah, Anta Rabbu kulli shay-in wa malikuh - Ashhadu an la ilaha illa ant, wahdaka la sharika lak, wa anna Muhammadan a'bduka wa rasuluk - A'udhu bika min sharri nafsi, wa sharrish-shaytani wa shirkih, wa an a-qtarifa a'la nafsi su-an au a-jur-rahu ila muslim
>
> <sup>Musnad Ahmad ([81](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/218)) Da'if since its Isnad is interrupted due to Mujahid (Ibn Jabr) who did not meet Abu Bakr and Layth (Ibn Abi Sulaym) is weak; therefore, it can not be raised to Hasan li Ghayrihi.</sup>

> 3x in the morning and evening: (Allahumma a'fini fi badani, Allahumma a'fani fi sam'i, Allahumma a'fini fi basari - La ilaha illa ant; Allahumma inni a'udhu bika minal kufr, wal faqr, Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min a'dhabil qabr - La ilaha illa ant)
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([5090](https://shamela.ws/book/117359/4310)) Shaykh Albani said in Tamam al-Manat (p. [232](https://shamela.ws/book/11122/254#p1)): 'The Isnad is Hasan or close to Hasan' since there is a dispute about the narrator Jafar ibn Maymun. Shaykh Hilal said in his Tahqiq of Ibn as-Sunni ([1/118](https://shamela.ws/book/123672/115)): 'Ahmad, Al-Bukhari, Ibn Ma'in [...] considered him to be weak; the Isnad is Da'if, and as for those of the scholars who have made it good; because this type of narrators are conflicting between being reliable or weak.'</sup>

> If anyone says in the morning or in the evening: O Allah, in the morning we call Thee, the bearers of Thy Throne, [...]
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([5069](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5069)) | Ibn Hajar classed it Hasan Gharib in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([2/375](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n374/mode/2up?view=theater)), but Shaykh Albani objected in Ad-Da'ifah (3/141-5 - #[1041](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/1556)) since A'bd al-Rahman ibn A'bd al-Majid is unknown and there is a difference of opinion if Makhul heard from Anas, Bukhari negated it. All of the other routes are also weak as the Shaykh has explained.</sup>
>
> <sup>Nevertheless, we have a **general** Hadith which is narrated in Al-Mustadrak ([1/704](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/1955)), and Al-Hakim classed it Sahih to which Imam Dhahabi agreed upon, and Shaykh Albani concurred in As-Sahihah (1/534 - #[267](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/531#p1)),  that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*Who says: Oh Allah, I bear witness to you and your angels and bearers of your throne, and I bear witness who is in the heavens and on the Earth, that you are Allah, there is no deity but you alone, without partner, and I bear witness that Muhammad is your servant and your messenger* (Allahumma inni ush-hiduka wa ush-hidu mala-i-kataka wa hamalata a'rshik, wa ush-hidu man fis-samawati wa man fil ard, Annaka Antal-lah, La ilaha illa ant, wahdaka la sharika lak, wa ash-hadu anna Muhammadan a'bduka wa Rasuluk) - *whoever says it once, Allah will ransom one-third of him from the Fire; whoever says it twice, Allah will ransom two-thirds of him from the Fire; whoever says it three times, Allah will ransom him entirely from the Fire.*"

> When you finish the Maghrib prayer, say: O Allah, protect me from Hell (Allahumma a-jirni minan-nar) seven times [...]
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([5079](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5079)), which Ibn Hajar classed Hasan in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([2/326](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/02_101274/page/n326/mode/2up?view=theater)), and Shaykh Albani objected in Ad-Da'ifah (4/127-9 - #[1624](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/2342)) - A misunderstanding happened here with the names of Muslim ibn al-Harith (Sahabi), the father of Al-Harith ibn Muslim, his son's status is unknown.</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>Nevertheless, there are two other Ahadith which should be rather followed **in general**:</sup></sup>
>
> <sup>Musnad Abu Ya'la ([6192](https://shamela.ws/book/181/5006)), classed Sahih in As-Sahihah (6/22-5 - #[2506](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/3550)), the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*No slave seeks protection from the Fire seven times in a day except that the Fire says: 'O my Lord, indeed your slave sought protection in You from me, so protect him.' And no slave asks Allah for Paradise seven times in a day except that Paradise says: 'O my Lord, indeed your slave asked for me, so enter him into Paradise.'*"
>
> <sup>Lastly, in At-Tirmidhi ([2572](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2572)), which Shaykh Albani classed Sahih in Talaq al-Raghib (4/222), that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*Whoever asks Allah for Paradise 3 times, the Paradise says: 'O Allah, admit him into Paradise', and whoever seeks refuge from the Fire three times, the Fire says: 'O Allah, save him from the Fire.*'"