What are some of best works on Islamic philosophy addressing Objective proofs for Islam?
Basically philosophical arguments and justifications for Islam.

List questions are hardly on-topic in the StackExxchange network. I strongly suggest you to check the [help] and take our [tour] to learn how this site works and what is on or off-topic here.

@Medi1Saif Okay but aren't these List type questions? https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/what-are-the-authentic-supplications-adyiah-and-rememberances-adhkar-at-faj

Yes, but they have a focus your question is totally open "etc., etc.", that makes the question not answerable within the scope of the our site and the SE network.

@Medi1Saif Okay then the problem is not that my question is "List type" but rather it lacks specificity.

Both are certainly issues, but let's say your example has first a focus secondly it doesn't cause issues and maybe a topic of interest for a broad public. Still another mod or community could declare it as off-topic I don't want to go around with the hammer till now and close it. So please consider elaborating your question to make it focussed.
